# Text preprocessing for fasttext pretrained models

Tags: nlp, text-processing, text-classification, fasttext

I want to use pretreained fastext model for language detection: https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/language-identification.html . Where can I find **the exact Python code** for text preprocessing used for training this specific model? I am not interested in general answers about how should we prepare text for using models - I ma looking for identical transformations as those used for training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Facebook engineers have been asked similar questions in their Github repository issues, they've usually pointed to [one](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/807#issuecomment-495552561) or [the](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/401#issuecomment-368935887) other of two shell scripts in their public code (& especially the 'normalize_text' functions within).

https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/tests/fetch_test_data.sh#L20

```
normalize_text() {
  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed -e 's/^/__label__/g' | \
    sed -e "s/'/ ' /g" -e 's/"//g' -e 's/\./ \. /g' -e 's/<br \/>/ /g' \
        -e 's/,/ , /g' -e 's/(/ ( /g' -e 's/)/ ) /g' -e 's/\!/ \! /g' \
        -e 's/\?/ \? /g' -e 's/\;/ /g' -e 's/\:/ /g' | tr -s " " | myshuf
}
```

https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/get-wikimedia.sh#L12

```
normalize_text() {
    sed -e "s/’/'/g" -e "s/′/'/g" -e "s/''/ /g" -e "s/'/ ' /g" -e "s/“/\"/g" -e "s/”/\"/g" \
        -e 's/"/ " /g' -e 's/\./ \. /g' -e 's/<br \/>/ /g' -e 's/, / , /g' -e 's/(/ ( /g' -e 's/)/ ) /g' -e 's/\!/ \! /g' \
        -e 's/\?/ \? /g' -e 's/\;/ /g' -e 's/\:/ /g' -e 's/-/ - /g' -e 's/=/ /g' -e 's/=/ /g' -e 's/*/ /g' -e 's/|/ /g' \
        -e 's/«/ /g' | tr 0-9 " "
}
```

They've also referenced [this page's section on 'Tokenization'](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html#tokenization) (which names some libraries), and the [academic paper which describes the earlier work making individual language vectors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.06893).

None of these are guaranteed to exactly match what was used to create their pretrained classification models, & it's a bit frustrating that each release of such models doesn't contain the *exact* code to reproduce. But, these sources seem to be as much detail as is available, without getting direct answers/help from the team that created them.